# How to determine the smaller and greater value based on user input?

Tags: c++11

I am trying to write a program that determines the smaller and greater value based on user input. But I am not sure how to do this. The integer values are stored into variables named val1 and val2. So the user enters a value into each of the variables, and I want the program to determine what is the smaller and larger number.

This is what my code currently looks like:

```
int main()
{
  int val1;
  int val2;
  cout<< "enter an integer followed by enter twice,\n";
  cin>> val1  >> val2;
  }
}
```

Comment: are you familiar with the mathematical operations `<` and `>`?

Comment: Once you've got a good grasp on conditional statements and comparison operators, now would be a great time to familiarize yourself with the [standard algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm). [`std::minmax`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax), for example, does exactly what you want. Here's a quick example: https://godbolt.org/g/wUYC8i

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for :

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int a, b, big;
    cout<<"Enter two number : ";
    cin>>a>>b;
    if(a>b)
    {
        big=a;
    }
    else
    {
        big=b;
    }
    cout<<"Biggest of the two number is "<<big;
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of finding the greater value.

```
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int a, b, big;
    cout<<"Enter two number : ";
    cin>>a>>b;

    cout<<"Biggest of the two number is "<<a>b?a:b; // ternary operator is used instead of checking with if condition.
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use *std::max* (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/).